# Installed Python packages disappear during layered Docker build

Tags: python, docker, pip, package

I have a root image which is tagged as `repo_a/image_a`. Its Dockerfile looks like so

```
FROM some_repo/some_image

# ...

RUN pip3 install https://$authToken:x-oauth-basic@github.com/library_a/archive/v0.0.1.tar.gz

# ...
```

`library_a` is a custom python library using `setuptools` for installation. Its installation file looks like

```py
setuptools.setup(
    name=library_a
    version=...,
    author=...,
    author_email=...,
    description=...,
    url=...,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'luigim = ....luigim:main',
            'luigip = ....luigip:main'
        ]
    },
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'luigi==3.0.3',
        'boto3==1.18.52',
        'influxdb',
        'boto',
        'paramiko',
        'termcolor',
        'retrying'
    ]
)
```

Now I am using this root image to create another image tagged like `repo_a/custom_image`. Its Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM repo_a/image_a

# ...
RUN pip3 install https://$authToken:x-oauth-basic@github.com/library_b/archive/v0.0.45.tar.gz

RUN pip3 install https://$authToken:x-oauth-basic@github.com/library_c/archive/v1.0.43.tar.gz

# ...
```

Both libraries a and b are custom Python libraries also using setuptools for installation. Their `setup.py`s look like

```py
setuptools.setup(
    name=library_b, #or c
    version=...,
    author=...,
    author_email=...,
    description=...,
    url=...,
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'luigi==3.0.3'
    ]
)
```

This is successfully built but my problem is that `library_a` installed in `repo_a/image_a` is no longer installed in `repo_a/custom_image`. To be more specific:

Libraries `library_b` and `library_c` are properly installed in the final image - I can see both in the result of `pip3 freeze`. Unfortunately, I cannot use them since they have a dependency on `library_a` which does not show up in the `pip3 freeze` output

If I remove the `pip3` installs from the second docker file, `library_a` can be found in the final image - I can see `library_a` in the result of `pip3 freeze` and can successfully import them in a python3 REPL.

So what happens here? it seems like the second set of `pip3 install` shadows the first `pip3 install` ran by `repo_a/image_a`. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried installing all three libraries in `repo_a/custom_image`? Just to test if they don't cause uninstalling library_a

Comment: @QuentinCaffeino Unfortunately this is not an option

Comment: I understand that you have the end goal, but I asked to do that only to test my assumption. Could it be that running pip install also removes this package. Also to analyze the build you can use 'dive' program. It shows each layer, what commahd was executed and what had changed on filesystem.

Comment: @QuentinCaffeino I fixed it in a hacky way but i think I'm going to stick with this. I had to reinstall library_a in the second dockerfile plus `pip3 install boto` and `pip3 install retrying` since they were also not installed after `library_a` was installed - although they are included in the required list.

Comment: This https://github.com/wagoodman/dive tool is amazing